# Two python application if run simultaneously on windows 7 crashes after sometime

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

We have created Two python (3.6) application one for object detection in video using tensorflow and another one GUI based on pyside2.

Both applications are running fine with out crashing if run one application at a time.

But if run simultaneously on windows 7, after some time (some time after one hour or two) crashes with Ntdll.dll error code c0000374.

We are using NVidia graphics card, cuda, numpy etc

New to python & tensorflow

Comment: Do both crash or just the one (which one)? What is memory usage looking like? Do they interact at all?

Comment: Only one of them crash (mostly GUI). No they don't interact. The system has 16GB RAM and 6GB GPU.

Comment: The error code relates to memory heap corruption (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvin_hsia/2015/01/30/heap-corruption-exception-0xc0000374/)  What is the memory _usage_ of the apps, eg find the process in task-manager? Might be nothing wrong with your code and could be a hardware issue, or an issue in a GPU driver. These kinds of bugs can be very hard to diagnose.

Comment: Memory usage RAM - < 8GB, GPU - < 2GB and CPU - 70 - 80 %

Comment: Sounds like `pythoncom` errors. Maybe can't **initialize** some threads in your apps.

Comment: @ dsgdfg - any idea how to fix this?